# How to use a segue with a table view but NOT a table viewController on my storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios

Ok so I have been searching for solutions all day long but nothing has popped up that works.
When the user selects "vrijdag" (= Friday in Dutch) the second ViewController opens.

What does work: I can select the first viewcontroller which is linked to a navigationcontroller and rightclick and drag to the second Viewcontroller BUT not from the Table View that I have added to the first ViewController

I have tried multiple tutorials but they all use a table view controller and not a view controller with a table view in it :)

Does anyone have a solution for this?
Of course it is important that I also know which cell was clicked so the next Viewcontroller displays the right information.

[image: My ViewController with the Table View in it]

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

Make your view controller a `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`. Then set your delegate in `viewDidLoad`: `self.myTableView.delegate = self`.

Then, simply implement the datasource and delegate methods in code, particularly this one:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myCustomSegue" sender:indexPath];
}
```

EDIT:
Here's how to set up a manual segue in IB. First, select your first view controller, control+click and drag to your second view controller, and select "push" from the small menu.

[image]

Then, name your segue by clicking on the segue itself (the circle on the line between the view controllers). Then go to the Attributes Inspector on the right side, and you will see a field named Identifier. Type in the name you want.

[image]

After doing this set up, the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method should work.

One more note: you can set up how your segue works in the method `prepareForSegue:sender:`. Here's a sample implementation. Replace the class and attribute names with your custom classes. Notice that you can set your destination's public properties from this method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender //sender should be an NSIndexPath object
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"myCustomSegue"]) {
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = sender;
       MyViewController *secondViewController = (MyViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
       UITableViewCell* cell = [self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
       secondViewController.name = cell.textLabel.text
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 agree.  maybe make the answer more clear with quick instruction on setting up the myCustomSegue in IB.

Comment: So what did I do: In the storyboard it self I richtclick dragged the tableview to the controller and selected datasource + delegate. In my .h file I have put <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> and I have made an outlet for the table and linked it. Then in the viewDidLoad i put what you told me to.
Then I put the method there but there is a problem with "self" --> No visible @interface for 'ViewControllerTest' declares the selector 'performSegueWithIdentifier'. Any idea? :p

Comment: Sorry, I got the method wrong! It's actually `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`. I edited my answer and added some things. Hopefully it's more helpful now!